# Any good duplicate photos finder based on photo contents omitting metadata?

Tags: photography, duplicate-files

I have a lot of duplicate photos. I can just use simple duplicate finder and compare all photos by checksum.

But this doesn't suit my conditions because most of my duplicate photos have different metadata (EXIF etc.) but the contents are identical! Comparing them by checksum will not give good results.

Also I tried to use advanced software which matches photos by similarities but I am not satisfied with the produces results.

To summarize all:

- I have many duplicate photos
- Most of them have different metadata but contents are identical
- I need software to find photo duplicates based only on CONTENTS omitting any metadata, filenames etc.

Tried:

- Duplicate Manager Pro
- Duplicate Photos Fixer Pro
- Photos Duplicate Cleaner
- Auslogics Software (Windows)
- Gemini

It doesn't matter what OS is required by that software, ever Linux, OS X, Win.

Comment: https://eprasartdff.codeplex.com/

Comment: https://kpaduplicates.codeplex.com/

Comment: https://duplifinder.codeplex.com/

Comment: I have linked 3 separate tools which I have used to varying success. I'll let you try them at your leisure as opposed to marking them as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

[digikam](https://www.digikam.org/) is primarily a photo organizer, but among other features it can search not only for identical but also *similar* images (e.g. resized versions).

Comment: That's very interesting. I will try. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

[DeDup-Image](https://github.com/DRRDietrich/DeDup-Image/) is a bash script to automatically find and delete identical images / duplicate photos, even if the metadata differs.
It always retains the largest copy, which probably contains the most metadata and deletes all other found objects based on the SHA256-HASH of the real image information without any metadata. Because the script needs to process a variant from each image without metadata, it's a bit slower and processor-intensive than programs or scripts that can only search for completely identical files.